# OpenLDAP: a custom base DN for a user

Tags: ldap, openldap

Is that possible to make OpenLDAP provide with different base DNs for different users?

Let me explain what exactly I want to acheive.

I have a domain (let's say, `dc=example,dc=org`).

I also have a phpLDAPadmin instance which purpose is to help me to manage this domain.

I also have a branch somewhere within this domain (let's say, `ou=foo,ou=bar,dc=baz,dc=example,dc=org`).

I also have a user (let's say, `uid=admin,ou=bar,dc=baz,dc=example,dc=org`).

I granted some permissions to this user to let them manage the branch I mentioned before (`olcAccess: to dn.subtree="ou=foo,ou=bar,dc=baz,dc=example,dc=org" by dn.exact="uid=admin,ou=bar,dc=baz,dc=example,dc=org" manage`).

The problem is that this user can't use phpLDAPadmin, because the OpenLDAP server propagates its base DN (by announcing the `namingContext: dc=example,dc=org` attribute, I guess), which the user doesn't have access to. So, phpLDAPadmin tries to show the user the contents of `dc=example,dc=org`, fails and laments that "This base cannot be created with PLA".

How to make phpLDAPadmin showing `ou=foo,ou=bar,dc=baz,dc=example,dc=org` as the base DN to this user instead of tryig to show them `dc=example,dc=org` which is not accessible at all?

Is there a way make OpenLDAP announcing with a different `namingContext` (`ou=foo,ou=bar,dc=baz,dc=example,dc=org`) to the user?

Or should I forget this idea and grant the user read-only access to each leave from the very top (`dc=example,dc=org`, `dc=baz,dc=example,dc=org`, `ou=bar,dc=baz,dc=example,dc=org`)?

Thank you.

Comment: That's a client configuration, not a server configuration. I'd just set up a second phpldapadmin with that configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I have no personal experience with phpLDAPadmin.

I'd recommend to modify the ACLs that the intermediate entries are visible for the user. At least grant read access to pseudo-attribute **entry**. You should probably do this in sort of a last-catch ACL.